# is there any way to validate a field that sometime is File(image) && sometime is String(Src of same image)

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-validation, laravel-request

my problem :
i am using laravel framework php

i want validate a field witch my field sometime is File(image) and sometime is String(src of same image)

is there any shortcut or solution in Laravel ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The specifics of your question are not exactly clear but I think you can manage what you want by doing something like:

```
$request->validate([
   'stringOrFile' => [
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            if (!is_string($value) && !($value instanceof UploadedFile)) {
                $fail('The '.$attribute.' must either be a string or file.');
            }
        }
 
   ]

]);
```

Where `UploadedFile` refers to `\Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile` and `stringOrFile` refer to the name of the input your are validating.

However if possible use a different name for the input depending on what it is so you can have more complex validation rules on each different input.

More details on these kinds of validation rules [in the manual](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#using-closures)

Comment: i have form in client that send me multi field that 2 field of its form is photo i want edit photo of my object in my program , and then i have one  rule that when client wont update one of photo it mean that this photo already updated and it just must send me SRC of its photo  and then i want check that what he had send  me SRC or File , just it

Answer (score 2):

Or you can do something like that in your request class ;)

```
/**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'image' =>$this->getValidationRule('image'),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param String $key
     * @return string
     */
    public function getValidationRule(String $key): string
    {
        if (request()->hasFile($key)) {
            return "nullable|mimes:png,jpg";
        }
        return "nullable|string";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually while using the form data, empty image is received as a string "null". you can manage this in your controller.

```
$request->request->add(['image' => $request->image==  "null" ? null : $request->image]);
$request->validate(['image'=> nullable|sometimes|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,svg])
```

or you can send an empty string in case if image is not attached.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code example. take any part useful for you.

```
$msg=[
        'name.required'=>'<span class="badge">Name</span> is Required',
        'username.required'=>'<span class="badge">User Name</span> is Required',
        'born.required'=>'<span class="badge">User Name</span> is Required'
    ];


    $request->validate([
        'name'=>'required|string|min:2|max:30',
        'username'=>'required|string|min:3|max:20',
        'born'=>'required|date',
        'image'=>'nullable|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,bmp,png'
    ],$msg);
```

$msg for errors

you should create error page blade name **error** contains

```
@if($errors->any())
{!! implode('', $errors->all('<div class="alert alert-danger">:message</div>')) !!}
@endif
```

///

in blade that contain form for validation write top code

```
@include('error')
```

include error page if exist any error to display errors